# Using jquery before the script includes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my one of the PHP project, part of it done by some other people. All the js scripts are loaded in **footer** file. The **html** closes at the footer file.
How Can I use jquery functions before the inclusion of **footer** file ?. Since using it after the **footer** file will show it after the closing of **html**. When I tired to use jquery functions before the **footer** I get the js error **$ not defined** etc.. I have searched many similar questions but couldn't find a solution. I can't change the file inclusion order currently since some other people have done it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use jQuery before the `<script>` tag that imports jQuery.

Comment: @Pointy Then what is the solution for this ? What is the best way to include the scripts?

Comment: You could put your code in an external .js file, and load it from the same footer code that loads jquery.

Comment: Just include every Javascript in your header... (like almost every website do)

Comment: @PLAudet actually it's suggested (and it's a really great idea) to put your script tags before the `</body>` closing tag.

Comment: Well i have always included my JS before the `</header>` tag

Comment: Actually, it is best practice now to put them in the header and use the async and defer attributes. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup) question and [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS) link from google about blocking js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, like you mention, *you have absolutely no control* over where jQuery scripts are included, you can set timer to check when jQuery is ready, e.g.:

```html
<script>
  var i = setInterval(function() {
    if ($) {
      clearInterval(i);
 
       $(document).ready(function(){
          alert('Ready!');
       })        
    }
  }, 100)
  
</script>  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But otherwise - if you can control it - include them before your code.

Answer (score 1):

this code will only run properly in modern browsers (IE > 8)

```
<div class="jq"></div>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    $('.jq').html('working');
});
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/2mmdrega/

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes did something like this:

```
    function JQueryManager(callback, thisArgument) {

        this.execute = function() {
            if (typeof jQuery == "undefined") {
                console.log("Waiting for jQuery...");
                var self = this;
                var selfArgs = arguments;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    self.execute(selfArgs)
                }, 100)
            } else {
                console.log("Found jQuery. Version: " + jQuery.fn.jquery);
                callback.apply(thisArgument, arguments)
            }

        }
    }

    function myCallback(results) {
        alert("found " + results.length + " results")
    }


    var jQueryManager = new JQueryManager(myCallback);
    jQueryManager.execute($("div"));
```

That allows you to execute a callabck function when jQuery is available

EDIT: fixed some copy-paste errores